# Converting bytes to char array - and back again

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm in the process of creating a program that extracts binary/byte data of a double number and convert it to hexadecimal.  Then the reverse needs to be applied: convert the hexadecimal back to bytes so it can once again be used as a double.

This is something that I am investigating for a project.  The thinking behind it is that "Some accuracy can potentially be lost by saving double values in ASCII form, as opposed to saving its byte value" - according to my supervisor.  These values are to be saved and read thousands of time, so accuracy of the original double value is important.

Personally, I don't see the problem.  For example, I have the following code that extracts the bytes of a double from memory, and converts it to hexadecimal.

```
string double_to_hex_string(double d)
{
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*)&d;

    int bufferSize = sizeof(double);

    char converted[bufferSize *2];

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = bufferSize - 1; i >= 0 ; --i)
    {
        sprintf(&converted[j*2], "%02X", buffer[i]);
        ++j;
    }

    string hex_string(converted);
    return hex_string;
}
```

The double value 0.61 is represented in memory as 0.60999(re-occurring).  However, both values produce the same hexadecimal value - because these numbers are the same and can only be represented in one way.  This is my thinking, but I've been told to investigate, anyway.

My main question is to do with converting between types - especially back from a string hexs to a double value.  I'm using a lot of code off the Internet without understanding how bytes are represented.  My current understanding is:

- Numbers of type double (or any other type) are stored in memory are values that range from 0 - 255.  Thus, unsigned chars are a sensible way of holding those byte values (one byte).
- These char values are just 8-bit integer numbers.  And can be converted easily into hexadecimal.

In order to convert back, my guess of the steps are (just the reverse):

- Convert each pair of hex values in the string to a unsigned char.
- Collect these char into an array.
- Cast the array of chars back to double (somehow).

I would be grateful for any guidance with this - especially with anything that I may overlook in my conversion, and any corrections on the statements that I have made in the above text.

Comment: I don't get it. If the values "are to be saved and read thousands of time" (sic), why not simply store them as is? Why convert them to hex strings? The conversion takes time, and the hex string takes up twice the memory. What do you gain?

Comment: Because, apparently, there's a loss of accuracy by storing numbers in ASCII form.

Comment: By the way, yes, there are problems in your code... e.g. if by `string` you mean `std::string`, you can't put the char array `converted` into it like that, because `converted` isn't zero terminated.

Comment: No, I didn't say store in ASCII form, I said use as is. Not convert them at all.

Comment: @MrLister: I'd guess maybe he has to transmit them, and doesnt know how to send a double over his protocoll?

Comment: @MooingDuck Could be. Then if there are many of these doubles to be sent, I'd suggest something like BASE64. But I need to know what his needs are.

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but the `converted` array needs to be bigger by 1 to make room for the null terminator.

Comment: Transmission over a network my be involved.  The double numbers will need to be stored to file at various points, and loaded from file to be used once again.  I'm trying to investigate whether accuracy is lost between 'memory' state and textual state i.e. ASCII

Answer (score 2):

OK, some answers. Let's assume, for the sake of the argument, that this is about the most common definition of double, namely the 64 bits IEE 754 standard.

Because of the way that these things work, it's possible to express the value of a double precision variable exactly in decimal. For instance, you can store 2^200 in one, and you'd be able to write that accurately as a decimal number with 61 digits. Nobody ever does that, but believe me, it's possible.

Where the deterioration comes in is when you try to store things in a double that can't be expressed exactly in its format, for instance 1/7. The nearest approximation is a number starting with 16 correct digits after the decimal point, but if you think the rest of the digits are irrelevant, you'd be wrong. Writing only those 16 digits (i.e. the number .1428571428571428) to a file, and reading it back in, would result in a slightly different number than you had before, that differs more from 1/7.

So yes, if you must write the number to a file and read it back in, don't do it like that. When you can't simply write the "native" byte content to a binary file, using 16 hex digits is a valid alternative.
Here you go. If we assume, again, that double is 8 bytes, you won't need a variable length buffer, and no loop.

```
string double_to_hex_string(double d)
{
    char converted[17];
    sprintf(converted, "%016llX", *((uint64_t*)&d));
    return std::string(converted);
}
```

By the way,

> The double value 0.61 is represented in memory as 0.60999(re-occurring).

is not entirely correct, that's only 14 nines repeating. (After that, there are other digits.) If there were an infinite number of nines, that would be an exact representation of 0.61!
The rest of your assumptions are OK.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Unfortunately, I don't think I will be able to use unit64_t in my own code as it's a new language feature (I have to think about portability).  Was the original code I posted not suitable (it works)?  In addition, I would be grateful for any info regarding transforming the resulting hexadecimal value back into memory.

Comment: No, your original code was not OK. Allocate at least one more char than the number of characters you're going to store, because you need room for the zero terminator. Otherwise, it looks OK. But where do you get the information that `uint64_t` is a new language feature?

Comment: Using the header file <cstdint>, g++ compiler says the following: 

<error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.>

Comment: Hm... interesting. I didn't know that! I had `<stdint.h>`. Sorry.